# Phantomjs update values of var?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have the below phantomjs program where the website contains a drop down list **ddlLevel3**

```
var page = require('webpage').create(); 
    page.onConsoleMessage = function(str) { 
       console.log(str); 
    } 
        var z=0;
var z_l=0;
var op1='#ddlDivision'
var op2='#ddlLevel1'
var op3='#ddlLevel2'
var op4='#ddlLevel3'


function selectOption(selector, optionIndex) {
    page.evaluate(function(selector, optionIndex){

    var op4='#ddlLevel3'

        var sel = document.querySelector(selector);
    var sel4 = document.querySelector(op4);
        sel.selectedIndex = optionIndex;

    var event = document.createEvent("UIEvents"); // See update below
    event.initUIEvent("change", true, false);
        sel.dispatchEvent(event);
    this.dispatchEvent(event);

    z_l=sel4.length;
        console.log("len: "sel4.length+" "+z_l);
    }, selector, optionIndex);
}


page.open(...{
function loop4 () { 

   selectOption(op4,z);
   window.setTimeout(function () {    
      go();          
      z++;                     
      if (z < z_l) {            
         loop4();             
      }  

   }, 3000);
}
loop4();
});
```

I am trying to run **loop4()**. But the value of **z_l** is not changing from '0'.

In line **console.log("len: "sel4.length+" "+z_l);** Here values is proper.

But its not reflected back in **loop4()** in **if (z < z_l)**, and remains **0** always.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, your variables are not very semantic and thus are hard to debug. Could you maybe refactor a little? Also - please publish a full minimal example, `page.open...` is not helpful.

Comment: @Vaviloff I wanted to update the value of z_l everytime selectOption() is called().I think I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I I wanted to get the value of z_l updated.I just need to use page.evaluate and assign it to z_l as below. Just made these changes in loop4().

```
function loop4 () { 
var z_l = page.evaluate(function() { 
    var op4='#ddlLevel3'  
      return document.querySelector(op4)
   });

selectOption(op4,z);
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Is this the answer to your own question?

Comment: @Vaviloff yup that's the answer which I figured out later.